# Convert a dictionary of strings to a dictionary of numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop, numpy-ndarray

I have a dictionary structured similar to below.

```
test_dict = {1: 'I run fast', 2: 'She runs', 3: 'How are you?'}
```

What I'm trying to do is convert all the strings to 4x4 numpy arrays where each word is in it's own row and each letter occupies one cell of the array, populated with blanks for lines that wouldn't fill the entire row a whole row of blanks for sentences that are less than 4 words long. I also need to be able to tie it back to the ID, so the result needs to be in some format that can allow for referencing each array by it's ID later on.

I don't know of any pre built functions that can handle something like this, but I would be happy to be wrong. For now I've been trying to write a loop to handle it. Below is obviously incomplete because I'm stuck at the point of creating an array in the structure I would like.

```
for k in test_dict.keys():
    sentence = test_dict.getvalues(k)
    sentence_ascii = [ord(c) for c in sentence]
    sentence_array = np.array(sentence_ascii)
```

Comment: You can create structured numpy array to have your IDs access your arrays and call them using the ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This'll ensure you have blank rows for sentences less than four words long.

```
new_dict = {i+1:np.empty((4,4),dtype='str') for i in range(len(test_dict))}
for k,v in test_dict.items():
    new_dict[k][:len(v.split())] = np.array([list(s)+['']*(4-len(s)) for s in v.split()])
    new_dict[k] = new_dict[k].view(np.int32)
```

Comment: I apologize, one thing I forgot to add is I need to convert to ascii values. Is that easily incorporated into your solution? I'm having some trouble with converting the resulting dictionary arrays to ascii.

Comment: Yes it's easy. For any array of characters, array.view(np.uint8) gives the ascii equivalent. I've edited in the line into the code, see if it works.

Comment: It seems like there is way more than a 4x4 array now. It looks like maybe each array is now 4x16? I'm not sure the best way to share what I'm seeing so I'll stick it in the original question as an edit.

Comment: Oh sorry. uint8 breaks the strings into 4 chunks. np.int32 should work, just tested it.

Comment: This is awesome, thank you. I have one more question out of curiosity, I notice that within a sentence, this method converts any empty array cell to a 32 (ascii for space) but for the empty line it converts it to 0 (which makes sense). For my purposes it would be ideal if the only 32 values were actual spaces, and the rest would be 0. So that first line of the first string array would look like [73,32,0,0] rather than [73,32,32,32]. If that's not a simple edit I will do some digging on my own, thanks again!

Comment: An easy fix would be to add an extra line, converting all 32s in each array to 0, or converting all spaces to blanks before ascii conversion. Another solution is instead of left justifying and filling the word with spaces, you can manually add blank '' characters in a list. I've edited this one into the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

```
{
    key: np.array([list(word.ljust(4)) for word in val.split()])
    for key, val in test_dict.items()
}
```

output:

```
{1: array([['I', ' ', ' ', ' '],
           ['r', 'u', 'n', ' '],
           ['f', 'a', 's', 't']], dtype='<U1'),
 2: array([['S', 'h', 'e', ' '],
           ['r', 'u', 'n', 's']], dtype='<U1'),
 3: array([['H', 'o', 'w', ' '],
           ['a', 'r', 'e', ' '],
           ['y', 'o', 'u', '?']], dtype='<U1')}
```

Comment: This is close, one thing is it seems to only create 3x4 arrays, and as I mentioned to the other solution above I apologize but I forgot to also mention I'm trying to convert the letters to ascii.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to call your arrays using field 'ID':

```
dt=[('ID', '<i4'), ('sentences', object)]
new_dict = np.empty(len(test_dict), dtype=dt)
for i, (k, v) in enumerate(test_dict.items()):
  new_dict[i] = (k, np.pad(np.array([list("{:<4}".format(w)) for w in v.split(' ')]).view(np.int32), [(0,4-len(v.split(' '))),(0,0)]))
```

example output:

```
print(new_dict[new_dict['ID']==2]['sentences'])

[array([[ 83, 104, 101,  32],
   [114, 117, 110, 115],
   [  0,   0,   0,   0],
   [  0,   0,   0,   0]], dtype=int32)]
```